# Mass User Profile Management

Tags: user-profile, delegate

Is it possible to script (or otherwise) a series of changes to a number of Profiles at the same time (such as automatically setup delegates for a number of accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Usually you iterate a list of users which are of interest and update a property. One command to have a closer look at is [Set-SPUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607827.aspx).

Comment: @Razzmos You're welcome! If you need assistance in iterating with PowerShell - search here or ask again ;)